# How to lift state with an on-click event

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent and a child component. The child changes the colour of a div and updates the winner and selected elements in state. I have a button in my parent. On submit, I need to lift the winner data into an array in my parent component and send this on to Redux. I've tried sending down a callback, but as I already need to trigger an on-click event within the child I can't work out how to do this.

Parent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MatchCard from "../MatchCard";
import Shuffler from "../Shuffler";

class TournamentGrid extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      winners: [],
    };
  }

  render(playerNames) {
    let shuffled = Shuffler(this.props.playerNames);

    let newArr = shuffled.reduce(function (result, value, index, array) {
      if (index % 2 === 0) result.push(array.slice(index, index + 2));
      return result;
    }, []);

    console.log(newArr);

    return (
      <div className="inline-block flex justify-center">
        <div className="ml-2 mr-2">
          {newArr.map((players, index) => (
            <>
              <MatchCard
                key={index}
                players={players}
                handleWinner={this.handleMatchCard}
              />
            </>
          ))}
          <div className="inline-block flex justify-center">
            <button
              className="m-6 block bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-500 rounded w-55"
              onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
              {shuffled > 2 ? "Next Round" : "Final"}
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TournamentGrid;
```

Child

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PlayerCard from "./PlayerCard";
import Shuffler from "./Shuffler";

class MatchCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: 0,
      winner: "",
    };
  }

  render(key, players) {
    let arr = this.props.players;
    return (
      <div className="mt-4 mb-4">
        <>
          <PlayerCard
            player={arr[0]}
            selected={this.state.selected === 1}
            handleClick={() => this.setState({ selected: 1, winner: arr[0] })}
          />
          <PlayerCard
            player={arr[1]}
            selected={this.state.selected === 2}
            handleClick={() => this.setState({ selected: 2, winner: arr[1] })}
          />
        </>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MatchCard;
```

Comment: ... Call the function you pass in the click handler?

Comment: Do you mean declare the function in the parent?

Comment: ... You're passing a property already, `this.handleMatchCard`. It would kind of *have* to be defined at the time you pass it, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback function as prop to the MatchCard Component that receive the winner something like:

```
// This method is defined on the Parent component.
const handleWinnerSelect = (card, selected) => {
    this.setState(e => {
        // u need to handle how the selected element is pushed on the array
        // and how remove the previous one.
        const new_state = {...e}
        new_state.push(selected)
        return new_state
    });
}
```

now in the render method you can render the children with this method as prop. so
on the MatchCard you handle the click event and call the **handleWinnnerSelect**